# Shape error in Tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I wanna use CNN for 1D data, so decide to use `conv1d` layer. First two layers goes good, but when I create second conv layer, I have and error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 586 for 'conv1_43/conv1d/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [586,1,1040,1], [1,5,586,6].
```

This is my date shape:

```
trainX = dataX[0:616]
trainY = dataY[0:616]
testX = dataX[616:646]
testY = dataY[616:646]

trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, axis=2)
testX = np.expand_dims(testX, axis=2)
#final shapes: train:(586,1040,1) test:(30,1040,1)
```

There's code:

```
def new_conv_layer(input, num_input_channels, filter_size, num_filters, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        # Shape of the filter-weights for the convolution
        shape = [filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]

        # Create new weights (filters) with the given shape
        weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

        # Create new biases, one for each filter
        #biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[num_filters]))

        # TensorFlow operation for convolution
        layer = tf.nn.conv1d(input, weights, 1, 'SAME')

        # Add the biases to the results of the convolution.
        #layer += biases

        return layer, weights


# Function for creating a new ReLU Layer

def new_relu_layer(input, name):

    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        # TensorFlow operation for convolution
        layer = tf.nn.relu(input)

        return layer

 # Convolutional Layer 1
layer_conv1, weights_conv1 = new_conv_layer(trainX, num_input_channels=586, filter_size=5, num_filters=6, name ="conv1")

# Pooling Layer 1new_pool_layer
layer_pool1 = max_pooling1d(layer_conv1, 3, 1, name="pool1")

# RelU layer 1
layer_relu1 = new_relu_layer(layer_pool1, name="relu1")

# Convolutional Layer 2
layer_conv2, weights_conv2 = new_conv_layer(input=layer_relu1, num_input_channels=1, filter_size=5, num_filters=16, name= "conv2")

# Pooling Layer 2
layer_pool2 = max_pooling1d(layer_conv2, 2, 1, name="pool2")

# RelU layer 2
layer_relu2 = new_relu_layer(layer_pool2, name="relu2")
```

What is a problem?

Comment: What's the point for using "CNN for 1D data"? Do you mean a layer where you apply convolution like function in 1D data, because in general CNN means 2D data?

Comment: I know tha CNN is more for 2D data like images, but I have 1D vector with 1040 values, where I need to apply convolution

Comment: 1D convolutions can be useful for edge detection in 2d images and whatnot as well so that no big issue. this just looks like you need to go back a print the sizes of all your tensors and probably re-think the shape your filter banks should have though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` and `kernel` sizes to the `nn.conv1d` is not right.

From the [API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d),

> 1. Input tensor should be of shape: `[batch, in_width, num_input_channels]`
> 2. Kernel/weights should be of shape: `[filter_width, num_input_channels, 
>      out_channels]`

The inputs are of shape `[586,1,1040,1]` and should be `[586, 1040, 1]`, and the kernel has the `num_input_channels` defined wrongly when calling the `new_conv_layer`. It should be 1 in the first call and 6 in the next call.